# How do I get the website name when from a WebBinding using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis-8

So I'm writing a Powershell script to validate all HTTPS bindings of all websites actually have a respective SSL binding. I know this sounds pointless, becasue the IIS Management interface already validates this when trying to save such a binding, but trust me when I say this isn't always the case when you have a mix of bindings in a shared IIS configuration, where some bindings use certificates from the CCS and some use locally installed certificates.

I've already written a script that can provide me with a list of website bindings, that don't have a corresponding SSL binding. This list is compiled using the `Get-WebBinding` scriptlet.

I'm probably overlooking something very simple, but does anybody know how to determine the website name from just a WebBinding?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a way to do this afterall:

```
function GetWebsiteName() {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $binding
  )

  $binding.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1'
}
```